# Mongodb: Insert key:value into object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In my playing with Mongodb over the past few weeks I am developing more and more complex applications, in my latest project i would like to insert a `key:value` into an object.  I am using `mongojs` & `node.js`.

I am generating a dynamic key (ie: `hash = 3gx83h7`) for my new key:value to be pushed into the object paths. I know I can do the following:

```
db.applications.update({'apikey':key,'uid':user._id}, {'$set':{'paths.hash':0}},function(err){
    if(!err){}
});
```

But that will push a key:value similar to this:

```
paths:{
    hash:0
}
```

How can i push in my generated hash as the key?

Comment: your code works exactly how you coded it. what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assemble the key name programmatically so that `hash`'s value is used:

```
var setValue = {};
setValue['paths.' + hash] = 0;

db.applications.update(
    {'apikey': key, 'uid': user._id}, 
    {'$set': setValue}, 
    function(err){
        if(!err){}
    }
);
```